# Undefined namespace prefix error when using xlink

Tags: image, xslt

i have this xml :

```
<figure>
    <objetmedia>
        <image typeimage="figure" xlink:actuate="onLoad" xlink:href="picture-02.jpg" xlink:show="embed" xlink:type="simple"/>
    </objetmedia>
</figure>
```

And i have this xsl script :

```
<xsl:template match="figure">
    <figure>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="objetmedia" mode="image"/>
    </figure>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objetmedia" mode="image">
    <img src='{image/@xlink:href}' />
</xsl:template>
```

But i have this error :

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): Undefined namespace prefix
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompiledEval:
> evaluation failed Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): runtime
> error: file script.xsl line 154 element img  Warning:
> XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): Internal error: Failed to evaluate
> the AVT of attribute 'src'.

Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the `xlink:` namespace prefix in your stylesheet, and bind it to the same namespace uri as the original document uses. You haven't shown the part of your input document that includes the namespace declaration, but if it's the standard XLink namespace then you'd need to add

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

to an appropriate place, usually your `xsl:stylesheet` tag.

The point is that XPath expressions and match patterns use the prefix bindings of the stylesheet, not of the input xml document. What matters for the matching is the namespace uri and the local name. Your stylesheet could equally well declare `xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` and then look for `@x:href` - as long as the namespaces match it'll find the right thing.